# Product Suggestions Based On Custom Customer Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute, data

Within our Magento shop customers don't really know what they need to buy. Therefore we want to give customers suggestions and advice what kind of product they could buy in our shop based on some input of custom attributes from our customers.

To determine this advice we want to define and collect several custom customer attributes.

*Customer Data:*

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|            | attr_1 | attr_2 | attr_3 | attr_4 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 1 |    2   |   10   |    3   |    2   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 2 |    8   |    3   |    4   |    4   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 3 |    5   |    2   |    3   |    9   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 4 |    4   |    2   |    1   |    4   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 5 |    3   |    8   |    2   |    2   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

We want to find which customers are similar to each other.

*Input:*

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer x |    7   |    4   |    4   |    4   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

*Output:*

```
"Most Similar To Customer 2"
```

And based on the order history of *customer 2* (and other similar users) we want to give buying advice.

Are there any best practises or any packages/extension which could help us further?